# Kubernetes Persistent Volume GCE Disk

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disk, persistent

I have created a GCE Disk and  I created a Persistent Volume with that Disk and claimed the PV successfully. But when I deploy the pod, it gives me an error. Below are the details.

**$ gcloud compute disks list**

```
NAME                    LOCATION                LOCATION_SCOPE  SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
test-kubernetes-disk  asia-southeast1-a  zone            200      pd-standard  READY
```

**pod.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /test-pd
        name: mypd
  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim
```

**pv.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-gce
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage:  200Gi
  storageClassName: fast
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: test-kubernetes-disk
    fsType: ext4
```

**pvc.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage:  1Gi
  storageClassName: fast
```

**Below are the events of the pod.**

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age   From               Message
  ----     ------       ----  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    12m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mypod to worker-0
  Warning  FailedMount  9m6s  kubelet, worker-0  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-gce" : mount of disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce failed: mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce --scope -- mount  -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce
Output: Running scope as unit: run-r4b3f35b2b0354f26ba64375388054054.scope
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk does not exist.
  Warning  FailedMount  6m52s  kubelet, worker-0  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-gce" : mount of disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce failed: mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce --scope -- mount  -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce
Output: Running scope as unit: run-ra8fb00a02d6145fa9c54e88adf81e942.scope
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk does not exist.
  Warning  FailedMount  5m52s (x2 over 8m9s)  kubelet, worker-0  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[mypd], unattached volumes=[default-token-s82xz mypd]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  4m35s                 kubelet, worker-0  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-gce" : mount of disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce failed: mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce --scope -- mount  -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce
Output: Running scope as unit: run-rf86d063bc5e44878831dc2734575e9cf.scope
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk does not exist.
  Warning  FailedMount  2m18s  kubelet, worker-0  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-gce" : mount of disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce failed: mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce --scope -- mount  -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce
Output: Running scope as unit: run-rb9edbe05f62449d0aa0d5ed8bedafb29.scope
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk does not exist.
  Warning  FailedMount         80s (x3 over 10m)  kubelet, worker-0        Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[mypd], unattached volumes=[mypd default-token-s82xz]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume  8s (x5 over 11m)   attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.NewAttacher failed for volume "pv-gce" : Failed to get GCE GCECloudProvider with error <nil>
  Warning  FailedMount         3s                 kubelet, worker-0        MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-gce" : mount of disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce failed: mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce --scope -- mount  -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce
Output: Running scope as unit: run-r5290d9f978834d4681966a40c3f535fc.scope
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ea05129-f32c-46f3-9658-2e5e0afc29af/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pv-gce: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/test-kubernetes-disk does not exist.
```

**kubectl get pv**

```
NAME     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM             STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pv-gce   200Gi      RWO            Retain           Bound    default/myclaim   fast                    23m
```

**kubectl get pvc**

```
NAME      STATUS   VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
myclaim   Bound    pv-gce   200Gi      RWO            fast           22m
```

Please kindly help with this.

Comment: The error is saying that `msales-kubernetes-disk` is not a valid persistent disk name.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `claimRef` spec in `pv`. you need to add  the `claimRef` field in `pv` which is going to help you to bound the `pv` with desired `pvc`.

and also make sure that pv and pod are in same zone.
GCE Persistent Disks are a zonal resource, so the `pod` can only request a `Persistent Disk` that is in its zone.

try to apply them :

**pv.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-gce
spec:
  claimRef:
    name: myclaim
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage:  200Gi
  storageClassName: fast
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: msales-kubernetes-disk
    fsType: ext4
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
          operator: In
          values:
          - australia-southeast1-a
        - key: topology.kubernetes.io/region
          operator: In
          values:
          - australia-southeast1
```

**pvc.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage:  200Gi
  storageClassName: fast
```

storage class should be like this:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  fstype: ext4
  replication-type: none
```

and pod should be like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
            operator: In
            values:
            - australia-southeast1-a
          - key: topology.kubernetes.io/region
            operator: In
            values:
            - australia-southeast1
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /test-pd
        name: mypd
  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim
```

Comment: $ kubectl get pvc
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
myclaim   Pending                                      fast           119s

Comment: After applying the provided .yml, now the pvc doesn't claim

Comment: I just created  the  GCE Disk using "gcloud compute disks create DISK_NAME" command. Do I need to format it to use in this case?

Comment: `gcloud compute disks describe  msales-kubernetes-disk` can you show me the output for this?

Comment: @Dusty i have updated my pv.yml. can you try the updated one please?

Comment: @Emon, still the pvc is pending. $ kubectl get pvc
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
myclaim   Pending                                      fast           19m

Comment: can you add the output for this command `kubectl describe pvc myclaim` ?

Comment: may be your disk and pods are in separate  zone . can you ensure that both are in same zone

Comment: if you done everything right then everything seems ok.

Comment: delete pvc pv and pod. and try to create again

Comment: @Emon, BTW, I just created the Disk using "gcloud compute disks create DISK_NAME \
  --size DISK_SIZE". Do I need to attach the created disk and format? I didn't do that,

Comment: And also I'm not running GKE Cluster. It's bare metal. Installed Kubernetes on top of GCP Compute Engines

Comment: And there are  only two pods running in Kube-System Namespace.

Comment: $ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                       READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-5677dc4cdb-nqhsh   0/1     Completed   0          2d17h
coredns-5677dc4cdb-v9799   1/1     Running     0          2d17h

Comment: Do I need to deploy a config file specifying cloud provider? --cloud-provider=gcp??

Comment: no actually it's not necessary. so far everything looks ok to me. the only thin that is bothering that as gce disk is a zonal resource so need to access it in same zone.

Comment: @Emon, it's working now. Since I'm running my cluster outside from GKE, we need to specifically provide --cloud-provider=gce parameter in api and contoller-manager conf file. BTW thanks for your support.

Comment: yup, got it. happy to here you have identify that problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Emon, here is the output for disk describe.

```
    $ gcloud compute disks describe test-kubernetes-disk
creationTimestamp: '2021-01-19T18:03:01.982-08:00'
id: '5437882943050232250'
kind: compute#disk
labelFingerprint: 42WmSpB8rSM=
lastAttachTimestamp: '2021-01-19T21:41:26.170-08:00'
lastDetachTimestamp: '2021-01-19T21:46:38.814-08:00'
name: test-kubernetes-disk
physicalBlockSizeBytes: '4096'
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-01/zones/asia-southeast1-a/disks/test-kubernetes-disk
sizeGb: '200'
status: READY
type: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-01/zones/asia-southeast1-a/diskTypes/pd-standard
zone: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-01/zones/asia-southeast1-a
```

Answer (score 0):

can you retry ? just delete everything.

follow this steps:

```
gcloud compute disks create --size=200GB --zone=australia-southeast1-a msales-kubernetes-disk
```

then apply this one

**pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myfrontend
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /test-pd
        name: mypd
  volumes:
  - name: mypd
    # This GCE PD must already exist.
    gcePersistentDisk:
      pdName:  msales-kubernetes-disk
      fsType: ext4
```

here you don't need to bother about `pv` and `pvc`

Answer (score 0):

@Emon, Still the issue exists. I just deleted everything. Deleted  the disk, pods, pv, pvc and storageclass. Just executed the provided pod.yml. And created the new disk.

```
$ kubectl describe pod test-pd
Name:         test-pd
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         worker-0/10.240.0.20
Start Time:   Thu, 21 Jan 2021 06:18:00 +0000
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  Status:  Pending
IP:
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  myfrontend:
    Container ID:
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /test-pd from mypd (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-s82xz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mypd:
    Type:       GCEPersistentDisk (a Persistent Disk resource in Google Compute Engine)
    PDName:     test-kubernetes-disk
    FSType:     ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-s82xz:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-s82xz
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age   From                     Message
  ----     ------              ----  ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled           59s   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/test-pd to worker-0
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume  8s    attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.NewAttacher failed for volume "mypd" : Failed to get GCE GCECloudProvider with error <nil>
```

BTW are you sure that I don't want to specify the cloud provider flag?